# Trying to take emails in a simple field, getting undefined method `signups_path' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, input

I've got a page which loads at home.html.erb and is controlled by the pages controller.

In the page, I have a form which is a single field that will be used to take email addresses.

The error I'm getting is:

```
undefined method `signups_path'
```

Here's my code for your reference, I'm not sure how exactly to define where the route is that it goes.

Home.html.erb contains this form:

```
    <%= form_for(@signup) do |f| %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :email %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :email %>
        </div>

        <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Enter" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

The `Pages` controller contains:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    @title = "Open Domain - Liberate your domains from obscurity"
    @signup = Signup.new
  end

end
```

The `Signup` controller contains:

```
class SignupController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @signup = Signup.new
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @signup = Signup.new(params[:signup])
    if @signup.save
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

end
```

And the `signup` model contains:

class Signup < ActiveRecord::Base

```
  attr_accessible :email

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates(:email, :presence => true,
                    :length => {:maximum => 40},
                    :format => {:with => email_regex})

end
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated it. I have a feeling this is a tiny problem and I'm a beginning dev. Thanks!

Comment: What's in your routes.rb file?

Comment: Nothing related to this. Haven't added anything, not sure what to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form_for(@signup) is trying to build a route to POST to.  If you don't have a named route in your routes.rb, you'll get this error. Try:

routes.rb

```
 post '/signup', :to=>"signup#create", :as=>"signups"
```

this basically says: When a POST to the '/signup' path is requested, route it to the create action in the signup controller.  Also, make a helper to this path accessible with the name: "signups_path"

Comment: What would you suggest I add to the routes.rb file

Comment: Can you explain a little more what this does? My signup box is located at home.html.erb which will be accessed by mydomain.com/. I'm confused by the post and :as sections and what they do

Comment: I think I added the explanation as you typed the comment.  You can also short circuit what form_for() is trying to do by specifying the path you want to POST to as @Yosep Kim suggests.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I'm now getting `uninitialized constant SignupControllerController` when I enter an email, but that's a topic for another question, I suppose.

Comment: nah, it was bad info from me, I updated the answer fixing the typo

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your form_for tag with this:

```
<%= form_for @signup, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
```

This will post it to "signup/create".